# Apply background image to div in django using javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I am building a quiz app using django where on Q.4 I have to display an image in the django template using javascript. I tried this in my .js file but didn't succeed:

```
document.getElementById("img").style.backgroundImage="url('images/image_name.jpg')";
```

Here `images` is the subdirectory in `static` directory.
The error I am getting is:

```
Not Found: /quiz/images/image_name.jpg
```

Here is my main `urls.py`
:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('quiz/',include('blogsite.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If images is a subdirectory of **static**, why would you use `'images/image_name.jpg'`.

This would just add the path images to the current path.

You have to declare the absolute path:

```
url('/static/images/image_name.jpg')
```